# Icon of items is not visible in Qlistwidget

Tags: qlistwidget

I am trying to fill the Qlistwidget in IconMode. I am calling a function for filling Qlistwidget from a thread class. In result, i am able to fill the items in widget but all the items are without icons. For filling the widget, i am using this:

```
QListWidgetItem *Items=new QListWidgetItem();
QFont f;
f.pointSize();
Items->setFont(f);
Items->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
Items->setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(filename))));
ui->listWidget->addItem(Items);
ui->listWidget->setWrapping(1);
Items->setSizeHint(QSize(100,100));
Items->setFlags(Items->flags()|Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
Items->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled|Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable|Qt::ItemIsSelectable);
Items->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
Items->setToolTip(filename);
```

Can anyone tell how to get the icon of thumbnails in Qlistwidget ?

Thanks,

Ashish

Comment: It should just work by Items->setIcon(QIcon(filename)), no need to make a Pixmap first.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know we can use but the result is same.

Comment: Hello Schuh,  Using Items->setIcon(QIcon(filename)) this working fine. But i want to do scaling my images in the grid of the Qlistwidget. thats why i have to use pixmap. Is there any other way to do the scaling of images in grid. your help will really appreciate.